# role of onehotencoding in Feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, feature-selection

I need to clarify about feature selection.

I am working on Kaggle breast cancer dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/reihanenamdari/breast-cancer). It is a categorical dataset. There are 15 features including one class level. So, to encode the categorical columns I need some encoding. I used labelencoder and onehotencoder. Now, if I go with label encoder I got the feature selection score for 15 features. However, if I go with onehotencoder I got feature selection for 39 features. I know why this was happened. Because onehotencoding transfer the dataset 0 1 format for all responses of a category.

Now the categorical dataset is a nominal categorical dataset. So, it is better to use onehotencoding rather than labelencoder.

code block for labelencoder and feature selection

```
fs = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k='all')
fs.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_train_fs = fs.transform(X_train)
X_test_fs = fs.transform(X_test)  

for i in range(len(fs.scores_)):
    print('Feature %d: %f' % (i, fs.scores_[i]))
```

Output for feature selection when using labelencoder

```
Feature 0: 18.397683
Feature 1: 0.907448
Feature 2: 1.948516
Feature 3: 61.664194
Feature 4: 270.739282
Feature 5: 290.261719
Feature 6: 4.682429
Feature 7: 12.392248
Feature 8: 0.668526
Feature 9: 921.736979
Feature 10: 7.633741
Feature 11: 19.629019
Feature 12: 20.830701
Feature 13: 1481.246548
Feature 14: 5428.386792
```

Code block for onehotencoding with feature selection

```
s = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k='all')
fs.fit(X_train, y_train)
X_train_fs = fs.transform(X_train)
X_test_fs = fs.transform(X_test)
for i in range(len(fs.scores_)):
    print('Feature %d: %f' % (i, fs.scores_[i]))
```

Output for onehotencoding and featureselection

```
Feature 0: 14.659096
Feature 1: 850.014288
Feature 2: 21.873525
Feature 3: 1485.277925
Feature 4: 5993.193209
Feature 5: 0.512006
Feature 6: 20.922138
Feature 7: 4.021212
Feature 8: 5.601705
Feature 9: 1.133983
Feature 10: 1.224111
Feature 11: 9.484409
Feature 12: 10.513141
Feature 13: 27.287016
Feature 14: 2.181016
Feature 15: 12.428941
Feature 16: 45.034507
Feature 17: 51.032404
Feature 18: 9.335082
Feature 19: 167.640306
Feature 20: 46.638949
Feature 21: 1.276569
Feature 22: 167.640306
Feature 23: 8.832149
Feature 24: 10.731865
Feature 25: 51.766011
Feature 26: 11.010064
Feature 27: 16.180921
Feature 28: 11.367710
Feature 29: 51.766011
Feature 30: 11.010064
Feature 31: 16.180921
Feature 32: 11.367710
Feature 33: 0.928991
Feature 34: 35.539577
Feature 35: 9.218108
Feature 36: 128.157306
Feature 37: 20.555553
Feature 38: 99.097837
```

My question is how could I use onehotencoding for feature selection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OneHotEncoding** is not used for feature selection. It is used for **encoding the categorical variables**. If you want to perform feature selection  there are a lot of techniques out there.

[Here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/feature-selection-techniques-in-machine-learning/) is a list of some of them.

[Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-real-and-categorical-data/) is an article which describes which technique to use when.

PS: OneHotEncoding is good for learning purpose but it is not the widely used technique when it comes to real world applications. There are other much better encoding techniques out there!

[Here](https://pypi.org/project/category-encoders/) is a pip library which contains almost all encoding techniques. Simple install using pip and start using!

**Cheers!**

Comment: Can you please share the link for better encoding techniques as well? Thank you.

Comment: @Encipher Sure. I've edited my answer to include a pip library for categorical encoders

Comment: strongly disagree with "it is not the widely used technique when it comes to real world applications"

Comment: @BenReiniger Being a Data Scientitst myself I've yet to come across an algorithm where the person has used OHE. Also the drawbacks of OHE outweigh any advantages it has so I am of the above opinion. But it is not to say that it is not used at all.